# How to build a ldap server that is same schema as active directory

Tags: java, active-directory, apacheds

I want to build a stub server using apacheds that has same schema as active directory.

We need to add custom attribute like:
userAccountControl, unicodePwd, ..etc.

I have no idea how to add this to the default schema programmatically.
Any idea?

apacheds version 2.0.0-M10

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where are you stuck? I'm pretty sure a search with a big searchengine would yield enough results.

Comment: I had the same challenge a couple of months ago. Do you only want to add a few attributes? If so, you might be able to do it with apacheds, but I had very-very bad experiences with it. No documentation at all, and all my experiments to extend its schema have failed. (It could be all my fault, of course.) Anyway I ended up sacking apacheds, and used the UnboundID java ldap sdk instead. With that I could load an exported Active Directory schema, which wasn't very easy either, but succeeded eventually. I can try to find something useful for you if you still need it.

Comment: Thanks @zagyi !! I still need it. I just want to add few attributes.

Comment: I added a few attribute. But it's very long code... I still want simple code.

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache DS Studio to define your own schema. You can use attributes and object classes from core, cosine or other schemas. Actually you can take MS AD schema and define the required object classes and attributes.

You probably will not be able to import AD schema directly in Apache DS as the formats would vary (even if they are both in LDIF), however, you can create the same classes and attributes in Apache DS schema (I recommend using different OIDs than MS).

You can then import the schema LDIF to Apache DS.